# How to use COSMctrl on QT/C++ application?

Tags: c++, qt, label, libraries, openstreetmap

I am fairly new at C++ in regards to GUI programming, for a project I need to use a Map viewer to draw routes from city to city. My class decided to use QT for everything related to GUI and Netbeans for code.

I read that the best framework using OpenStreetMaps is COSMctrl. However I have no idea how to use it. I have used JMapViewer to generate maps in Java and all it involved was importing the JAR files and adding the map to a JLabel.

How do I do that in a C++/QT application? I have no idea on how to make my program recognize COSMctrl and placing the map on a QTLabel for it to be displayed on my application.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`COSMctrl` uses `MFC` so you will have a hard time embedding this into `Qt`. However as far as I understand your problem you just need to display [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles). [Tiles](http://switch2osm.org/the-basics/) are just regular images and can be easily embedded in your program.

In order to know which tile you need to display for a given coordinate and zoom level, read [Slippy map tilenames](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) at the [OSM Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/). To learn more about how to obtain tiles, read section [Choosing a tile provider](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/) on [switch2osm.org](http://switch2osm.org/).